# Deactivate the menu dropdown

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

Site in consideration: http://dev5.99medialabtest2.com/bostoncenterless/

Scroll down the page so "Solutions to streamline your manufacturing process" heading go behind the menu. Then, hover over "Products & services" tab (which has a dropdown). Now, try take your mouse pointer to take over "Supply Chain Management" (appearing on the grey Solutions section) and you will see the dropdown won't let you go there.

Can someone please help to fix it?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In order for us to help you better, can you please update your question so that it shows your **relevant code** in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the **question itself**. External sites may be malicious or flagged by filter systems; users may not be able to visit them. It would also be helpful if you could let us know what you have tried so far to solve your problem. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) :)

Answer (score 1):

Lol, took me a while to recreate your problem.  If you move your mouse away from the dropdown menu for a longer period, say 2+ seconds, then you can get to "Supply Chain Management".  If you try to get to "Supply Chain Management" almost immediately after mousing away from the dropdown, the dropdown will reappear.

Why is this happening?  There is a transition happening when the dropdown disappears.  I think the problem is that the dropdown only looks like it is gone but isn't completely gone yet, so mousing back over the almost invisible dropdown makes it reappear.

The CSS causing the issue seems to be this in `.../wp-content/themes/bostoncenterless/custom.css`

```
/* Sub Menu */
ul.navbar-nav > li > ul.sub-menu{
    top: 65px;
    z-index: 111;
    left: -10px;
    min-width: 230px;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all .35s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .35s ease;
    -o-transition: all .35s ease;
    transition: all .35s ease;  
    -webkit-transform: translateY(20px);
    -moz-transform: translateY(20px);
    -ms-transform: translateY(20px);
    transform: translateY(20px);
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Here's what I would try

- Remove the `ease` from the four `transition` directives.  This transition might have the "long tail" that makes it almost invisible for an inconveniently long time.
- If that isn't better, you might have to remove the transition completely (delete the four `transition` and the four `transform` directives). You will no longer have the fancy exit by the dropdown but you'll also no longer have the very annoying UX issue. Your decision.
- EDIT: Another thought: Before the above two attempts, you might try changing `visibility: hidden;` to `display: none;`.  If that works, I'll explain it (otherwise nevermind).

Comment: Would be good to explicitly mention not to modify the original file but to override it with own CSS, IMHO. Better approach for maintenance, in case of theme updates....

Comment: @Axel.  Agreed!  I'm not a Wordpress guy so don't know the details of how but I agree 100% that if the CSS is not yours don't hack it, override it.

Comment: Here is a very quick and dirty hack for doing so: `add_action( 'wp_head', function(){
            echo '<style>/* CSS goes here */</style>';
        }, 99 );`. Just in case there is nothing else to [`wp_enqueue_style()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/).